# QueryDslPredicateExecutor cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

i'm currently upgrading my application,
dependency use

```
spring-core: - 5.3.27
spring-security: - 5.8.3
hibernate-core: - 5.3.1.Final
hibernate-search-orm:- 5.10.2.Final
hibernate-entitymanager: - 5.3.1.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api
hibernate-validator: - 6.1.6.Final
validation-api:- 2.0.0.Final
slf4j: -1.6.1
querydsl-apt:- 2.1.1
```

error code:-

```
extends JpaRepository<AssignmentBO, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<AssignmentBO>
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryDslPredicateExecutor;
```

eclipse suggestion: -

```
QueryDslPredicateExecutor cannot be resolved to a type
The import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryDslPredicateExecutor cannot be resolved
```

I tried changing the code(capital D and small d difference) to:-

```
extends JpaRepository<AssignmentBO, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<AssignmentBO>
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
```

but then my package starts give error

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    - The type com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

error line:-

```
package com.demo.backend.repository;
```

Comment: resolved this by changing the versions for querydsl